# How to get Object's Last Modified Date

Tags: describesobject, lastmodifieddate

I want to get the last modified date of a custom object definition in Apex or via  Schema.DescribeSObjectResult doesn't have a method like getLastModifiedDate.  But this info is clearly available in the custom object definition detail page.  Is there anyway to get this in the Apex code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Tooling API:**

Get the custom field's last modification date using the below query:

```
QueryResult queryResult = toolingConnection.query("SELECT Id, DeveloperName, LastModifiedDate FROM CustomField");
```

Get the custom object's last modification date using the below query:

```
QueryResult queryResult = toolingConnection.query("SELECT Id, DeveloperName, LastModifiedDate FROM CustomObject");
```

More information: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm